# Apache config on a Synology DS for use with mod_wsgi / Django

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi, synology

I'm started developing a new site using Django. For realistic testing I wanted to run it on a Synology DS212J NAS.
Following the official Synology guides I installed ipkg and with it the mod_wsgi package.
As Next step: Following the standard tutorial I made a virtualenv and installed Django in it. Opening a new project and adjust the settings following to: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-16-04
I'm able to reach the "Hello World" Site from Django by use of manage.py

As suggested I want to exchange the manage.py through the apache server on the NAS. So I think I should go and edit the apache config files for e.g. define a virtual host...
However I can't localize the files for it, as it seems they where moved at DSM6 (which I use) in comparison too other guides.

Where need I to enter the values following the Tutorial on the Synology?

As I'm quite new into the topic do I need to especially load the mod_wsgi module for Apache and if where?

Is it a good idea to use the basic mode of wsgi instead of the daemon mode? I'm not sure which Django modules will be used later on in development...

Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 0):

Activate the python 3 package and the webstation
In `webstation> general settings> main server http enable nginx`
In `Control Panel> Network> DSM Settings> Enable Custom Domain: "test"`
 (which will allow us to access the nas by entering test.local and simplify the task later.)
Enable ssh connection in `control panel> terminal and smtp`

We use the ddns service of synology to have external access in our case "test.synology.me"

In `control panel> security> certificate` : we generate our ssl certificate with let's encrypt
Connect to the nas in ssh
Take root rights `sudo -i`
Install virtualenv: `easy_install virtualenv`
We set up our virtual environment: `virtualenv -p python3 flasktest`

Flask and gunicorn are installed: 
`pip install flask gunicorn`
We create our web application, file: init.py
We launch our web application with gunicorn: 
`gunicorn --certfile /usr/syno/etc/certificate/system/default/cert.pem --keyfile /usr/syno/etc/certificate/system/default/privkey.pem -b 127.0 .0.1: 5000 app: app`
In `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` we create a server configuration file, we will use nginx as a proxy, in our case the file will be flasktest.conf
flasktest.conf file:

`
server {

```
listen 443 ssl http2;
listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

gzip on;

server_name test.synology.me;

location / {
    proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:5000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}

error_log /volume1/projects/flasktest/logs/error.log; 
access_log /volume1/projects/flasktest/logs/acess.log;
```

}
`

Open the `control panel port> external access> router configuration> create> integrate application> enable the check box for webstation and apply`

We check our server file for that we enter the command, `nginx -t`

We are restarting nginx `synoservicecfg --restart nginx`

You now have access to your python web applications from outside in https ** https: //test.synology.me**

a little more information ...
To end and access your application permanently if you will ever be able to reboot, crash ... you can create a script that will restart gunicorn because otherwise the webstation takes over elsewhere if you enter ip nas locally you do not will not see your web apps in python because we did not modify the main configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf locally so this is the default index.html page of the webstation that will be displayed.

example:

`cd / volume1 / projects / flasktest
source bin / activate
gunicorn --certfile /usr/syno/etc/certificate/system/default/cert.pem --keyfile /usr/syno/etc/certificate/system/default/privkey.pem -b 127.0.0.1:5000 app: app
</ dev / null 2> & 1 &`

This method found with other python framework